# Web Scraping href unrecognized

Tags: python, web-scraping

I ran similar code on another website and it works, but on opensubtitle.org I'm having a problem! I don't know why it is not able to recognize `href` (the link I need) and titles.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.opensubtitles.org/it/search/sublanguageid-eng/searchonlymovies-on/genre-horror/movielanguage-english/moviecountry-usa/subformat-srt/hd-on/offset-4040'

def scarica_pagina(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    cnt=0
    for film in soup.find(id="search_results").find_all("td"):
        cnt=cnt+1
        link = film.find("a")["href"]
        title = film.find("a").text
        #genres = film.find("i").text
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scarica_pagina(URL)
```

Comment: What is it you wanna grab from that page? Can you show us the expected output of a single container?

Comment: I would like to obtain the link to the dowlnload page of subtitles and the title of the relative film

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is to follow the DOM correctly:
1-first choose the table with id = 'search_results'.
2-find all td tags with class name 'sb_star_odd' or 'sb_star_even'.
3-find all('a')[0]['href'] for the link you want.
4-find all('a')[0].text for the title you want.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.opensubtitles.org/it/search/sublanguageid-eng/searchonlymovies-on/genre-horror/movielanguage-english/moviecountry-usa/subformat-srt/hd-on/offset-4040'

def scarica_pagina(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    cnt=0
    for film in soup.find(id="search_results").find_all('td',class_=re.compile('^sb*')):
        cnt=cnt+1
        link = film.find_all('a')[0]['href']
        title = film.find_all('a')[0].text
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scarica_pagina(URL)
```

**you were using find instead find_all that what caused your problem.**

Comment: It returns me this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cesma01/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 23, in <module>
    scarica_pagina(URL)
  File "C:/Users/cesma01/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 16, in scarica_pagina
    for film in soup.find(id="search_results").find_all('td',class_=re.compile('^sb*')):
NameError: global name 're' is not defined                                                              Which Python version are you using?

Comment: append it to the beginning of the file